# Baseline file support for pmd

Tags: android, pmd

It is hard to fix all pmd errors on an existing large Java project. This may cause regressions, and many refactors, changes everywhere.

I'd like to refer to the solution in Android lint tool, Android lint tool can create a baseline file in the repo, any errors recorded in the baseline file will be ignored. Once the baseline is set up, the next time we run the pmd tool, any new violations will be reported.

I search the doc but I didn't find any luck of something like baseline file in pmd.

Does pmd support baseline file feature? If so, how do I use this feature in an Android project?

Comment: PMD only reports on errors that you ask it to check on. It does that using _rulesets_. It sounds like you are using the default configuration, and getting a lot of unwanted errors. You can resolve that by creating a custom ruleset that could explicitly exclude the unwanted error reporting. See [Using Rule Sets](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html#using-rule-sets) for an overview, and [Making rulesets](https://docs.pmd-code.org/pmd-doc-6.53.0/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html) for details on how to customize the rules that PMD should follow.

Comment: For greater granularity you can also exclude the enforcement of specific rules from specific classes in your project. See [Violation Exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/violation-exclusions.html) for details.

Comment: @skomisa I want to exclude some files rather than exclude some rules. Does pmd support that?

Comment: If you have a Maven project then see [How to exclude a file for checking in PMD maven pom.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27225598/2985643). But you can also exclude specific classes, as mentioned in my second comment. Since there is generally a one-to-one mapping between classes and files in Java, this will effectively allow you to exclude by file in most cases. Or do you have edge cases in your projects where excluding-by-class rather than excluding-by-file would not work for you?